# 10 speed cassette/derailleur, but only getting 8 clicks?

Tags: derailleur, cassette, alignment

I've got a 2013 Giant Escape 0 Hybrid with a stock 10speed Shimano Deore rear derailleur.  My wife was riding the bike the other day, and somehow managed to shift in such a way that it popped the chain off the rear cassette and jammed in between the sprockets and the spoke protector.  Luckily no damage was done.

After putting the chain back on, I put the bike up on a stand to check/tweak the derailleur alignment.  The small sprocket and the large sprocket are properly aligned.  I can shift up and down with almost no problems; I seem to skip the third gear.

If I take the rear wheel off and click the derailleur, I only count 8 clicks; not 9.

I'm not sure what that means.  Nor am I sure how my derailleur can be properly aligned on the smallest and largest cogs, hit all the shifts except for one, and yet miss an index.

Is this an alignment issue?  Is there a problem with my shifter?  Is my derailleur whacked out of position?  How/why could I be "missing" an index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are skipping gears, I suggest the cable tension need to be reset. Shift to the smallest cog, undo the bolt fastening the derailleur cable and then refasten, ensuring there is just enough tension to hold the cable tight. You should then be able to accurately shift up one gear at a time and go through all 9 clicks. It may take a few attempt to get right, and you should test it with different front gears selected. Also check for worn cable or housings.

Looks like you need to set the limit adjuster also, there are two small Philips head screws that do this. They prevent the derailleur shifting past the largest and smallest sprockets.

Comment: Thanks - I've already adjusted the limit screws and like I said, I'm able to track the lowest cog all the way to the largest cog, but it skips one (the 3rd smallest).  I can't wrap my head around how the two outer limits can be right, and have the correct index spacing to switch from gear to gear, and yet still be short one index.  My next step is to re-tension the cable, but I'm still a little confused how this could even be.

Comment: I got it working.  I readjusted the cable tension and rechecked the limit screws.   I think the problem had been that the lowest cog was actually on the second click, so I lost a gear.  Whatever it was, I released the tension with the barrel adjuster, opened the bottom limit screw and readjusted for the lowest cog, and magically my missing gear reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The number of clicks is a logic test.
You start on gear one. Click once and you are on gear 2. Click 8 times and you are on gear 9.

Answer (score -1):

Rear mech is bent a little . If its shifting and on 2 of the gears shifting 2

Comment: OP has already stated it was a gear cable tension problem.  However you're right in that a bent hanger can cause all sorts of weirdness at the back end.